# do somethings after click copy button in clipbord

Tags: android, textview, clipboardmanager

i have text view and i want when long click on text open clipboard and when click copy button do some thing but i do not know how can get item click of clipboard.

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_en_body"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:longClickable="true"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/simple_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

By ClipBoardManager You can do that:

```
ClipboardManager
.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
  @Override
  protected void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
    //here to do what you want
    //to get text use: ClipboardManager.getText() 
  }
});
```